# Laravel AJAX call not working after reloading view?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a standard CRUD web app in Laravel that allows users to view and edit records. It also has a sorting mechanism that asynchronously (using AJAX) sorts the main records view.

This works fine until the user clicks on a record in the records view to edit it. Then they are redirected through the web router to a new Controller function that loads the update view for that record. When they click to save the SAME update function used to load the update view is fired a second time, and it updates the record and returns the ORIGINAL records view.

The problem is, the AJAX sort function for the records view only works BEFORE the update function is called. I've compared the HTML and JavaScript before and after a record is updated and it is IDENTICAL. So why does the AJAX function stop working?

My only guess is it has something to do with the web router. Predictably, the original read view is called with a GET method, and the update function uses POST, but I tried changing the "type" property in AJAX to POST with no luck.

Comment: Add some of the code here to take a look at it

Comment: Can you show us the java-script handler? I am suspecting, since the part of the page loaded, your java-script handler might not be correctly setup to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding _method=POST to your post data
Also do not forget to send csrf-token (axios does it automatically)